# More quotes in input method inside f string

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
print(f"Your name is {input("Your name: ")}")
```

Unfortunately, it gets confused the quotes.
I tried this, but it gives a `SyntaxError`:

```
print(f"Your name is {input(\"Your name: \")}")
```

This works:

```
print(f"Your name is {input('Your name: ')}")
```

However I have a convention of using `"` over `'` in this case, so you would you do this, using `"`?

Comment: Is it really necessary to put it inside an f string? Shorter code doesn't necessarily mean better code, such as in this case. It would be much better if you put your `import` somewhere else

Comment: I think F.M means *... put your `input` somewhere else.*

Comment: @ppwater Yes thanks for pointing that out lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes cannot appear inside the curly braces `{}` Doing so results in a SyntaxError.

See this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences

So, Just do this like the third code:

```
print(f"Your name is {input('Your name: ')}")
```

Or just do this (like F.M pointed out in the comments):

```
name = input()
print(f"Your name is {name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the input message beforehand:

```
nmsg = "Your name: "
print(f"Your name is {input(msg)}")
```

If just feel sorry for a single `'` you can use 3 of them:

```
print(f"Your name is {input('''Your name: ''')}")
```

squinting really *hard* this looks almost like a `"`.

Any other way to remove the complete input statement or at least the string delimited by " from the print statement works as well:

```
def NameInput():
    return input('''Your name: ''')

print(f"Your name is {NameInput()}")
```

As pointed out in the comment: the *cleanest* way to do it would be to put the input statement before the print statement.